# Fragment being destroyed when host activity resumes

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm working on an Android app and have noticed that after pausing and resuming the app (e.g. going to Home page or another app then returning to the original app), I am losing information from the fragment in between the pause and resume.  On debugging I found that when I resume the app the fragment is being destroyed by FragmentManager during the host activity's onResume.  (There is no code in the host activity's onResume which explicitly destroys the fragment.)

When I try and reproduce this in a simple app, it doesn't happen.

I can't see anything in the Android Lifecycle documentation which says the fragment gets destroyed when the app is resumed.

I'm ploughing through the FragmentManager code to try and work out why this is happening, but I'm wondering, does anyone know of any circumstance when this would happen / could you point me to documentation which explains this?

Let me know if you'd like more information or a link to the code. (I'm not expecting anyone to plough through the code, it's just if you want to get more information.)

Code snippet from host activity:

```
abstract class MainNavDrawerActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, Route.Listener {
...
   public override fun onResume() {
      ...
      super.onResume()  // (line 190)
      ...
   }
```

[debug stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUWpC.png)

Comment: I had the same problem in Java, and discovered that the library I used (default NavigationDrawer) was doing this. Are you using the FragmentManager and properly scheduling transactions? If not, you should check [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction).
In my case I just adapted my code and overwrote the default FragmentManager.

Comment: No problem, feel free to ask if you have further issues.

Comment: I have re tested the issue throwing an exception inside onDestroy() and printing the stack trace but now it seems that it only calls onDestroy() when I select another fragment and get back to the previous one (which is still a bit fishy as I wouldn't make that happen with my FragmentManager).
The trace comes from FragmentManager.moveToState() for me, I suggest you do the same and find where onDestroy() was called for your app. Let me know if you find something.

Comment: For me it's FragmentManager.moveToState(@NonNull Fragment f, int newState)  (though it's when I pause and resume the app) - can you see the link to the image in my post above which shows the stack trace?  I haven't got as far as working out why the variables have the values which cause it to do the destroy yet.

Comment: I just saw it and what the heck..? Why is onDestroy() called because of something in onResume()? This looks super weird @_@

Comment: If you need any help tell me, as soon as you will have enough reputation I'll move this to a chat as conversations in comments are not the best.

Comment: It disappeared also for me... When you'll be able just create a chat and invite me :>

Comment: I've deleted some of my "chatty" comments above to clean up, and I'll delete this one later, to save someone else the job.

Comment: Oops, I've now realised that, while the onResume doesn't explicitly destroy the fragment, it does _replace_ it, so that would explain why it is being destroyed.  (I didn't write the code and am still familiarising myself with it - I hadn't noticed that until now.)

Comment: Well they should at least provide a method to use the saved instance state, because replacing in *with a new one* in not necessary. I still prefer to use my own FragmentManager so that I don't run into these issues.

Comment: It's replacing with whichever menu option was chosen - I'll look into modifying it.

Comment: Should I delete this post, do you think?  Or do you think there is any value for others in me posting the relevant bits of code?

Comment: I don't think you should, maybe someone with not much experience will search something similar and this will help clearing their ideas : )
Apart from that, I want to make sure you get, that "replacing" does not necessarily involve using a new one, you have FragmentManager's methods (e.g.  addToBackStack, findFragmentByTag, ...) which can help you avoiding data loss when just changing fragment. If you need a better or more detail explanation search or just ask :>

Comment: I see, yes, replace just replaces the fragment in the container.  But it does seem to be passing a new instance for the fragment parameter.  (I really should post the code!)

Comment: That's what I said, it replaces with a new instance of the Fragment but I still haven't found a way to make it use a saved one. That's what I was pointing out with "replacing does not involve using a new one".
If you find something so that I don't have to override the default FragmentManager let me know because it would be pretty handy.